# Как реализовать перемещение в начало документа и обратно (в предыдущее положение) при клике только на одну кнопку? (код внутри)

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

на многих сайтах (пример вконтакте, хабр, пикабу) вижу, как при клике на кнопку мы сначала поднимаемся наверх, а при повторном клике спускаемся обратно, в то положение, в котором мы были, когда кликнули первый раз на кнопку, a при скроле записывается ее новое положение.
И при повторе операции, функция вернет нас уже в новое положение, но первый клик с текущего положения всегда поднимает нас наверх.

Попробовал написать следующий скрипт, где в атребут `data-effset` записывается текущее положение элемента при каждом клике, и все почти что работает, но если прервать выполнение функции прокруткой колесиком мыши или просто кликом по кнопке, не дожидаясь окончания прокрутки, то функция будет работать с ошибкой (перемещает нас между текущем положением и тем, где мы начали крутить колесико). Возможно надо ставить флаг, но совсем не соображу как...

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  scrtop = $(window).scrollTop()
  offsetnow = $(this).attr('data-effset');
  $(this).attr('data-effset', scrtop);
  $("body").animate({
    "scrollTop": offsetnow
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.folder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 25000px;
  background: #80CBC4;
}
#yack {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#button {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 33%;
  background: #E65100;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='folder'></div>
<div id='button' data-effset='0'>Вверх/вниз</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  // Ставим флаг, если true - идёт прокрутка, блокируем побочные действия
  let isWork = false;

  $('#button').click(function(e){
    // Если работает анимация, выходим ничего не меняя
    if(isWork)
      return;
    
    isWork = true; // Активируем флаг
    let scroll = window.pageYOffset,   // Текущий отступ прокрутки
        old    = +this.dataset.offset; // Старый отступ к которому будем крутить барабан :)

    this.dataset.offset = scroll; // Сохраняем новую позицию
    // Самое вкусное: запускаем анимацию по старому значению и по окончании онной,
    // меняем флаг в неактивное состояние, чтобы функция снова стала активной
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: scroll > 0 ? 0 : old
    }, 'slow', () => isWork = false);
  });

  $(window).scroll(e => {
    // Если наша прокрутка работает, отменяем стандартное действие
    if(isWork)
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.folder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 25000px;
  background: #80CBC4;
}
#yack {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#button {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 33%;
  background: #E65100;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='folder'></div>
<div id='button' data-offset=0>Вверх/вниз</div>
```

Comment: А для его нужно это  () =>  ? (после завершения анимации)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, это новая нотация для функций в `JS`. Решает наболевшее, но старые браузеры не понимают этого; благо уже достаточно давно есть поддержка.

Comment: да нет, я не понимаю для чего это, где почитать можно) понятно что после завершения анимации, переменная становится false, а () => это что значит, типа запуск функции?)) (тут совсем не понимаю, так то не смейтесь над предположениями)) то есть это isWork = false просто можно было бы засунуть в функцию и все бы тоже работало, правильно?)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, в данном случае, `() => {...}` может быть заменена на `function(){...}` (здесь не используются особенности **стрелочных функций**). Т. е. функция `animate` может принимать функцию, которую выполнит после завершения анимации, что нам и надо. Если поставить отмену флага просто следующей строкой, а не аргументом, то флаг сразу выключится, **не** дожидаясь конца анимации. Почитать про стрелки: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Если интересно - посмотрите данные по лямбда выражениям. Это как раз они. Очень удобный инструмент. Часто пользуюсь в Jave. Про появление их в JS узнал к своему стыду и радости сейчас. Спасибо, @Other!

Comment: @DimXenon, всегда пожалуйста, настоятельно рекомендую посмотреть все новинки, начните хотя бы отсюда: https://learn.javascript.ru/es-modern

Comment: @Other проверил сейчас скролл вверх/вниз. работает неправильно. Ткните по нему вначале, потом прокрутите ползунок вниз и снов ткните. Несколько разых вариантов попробуйте. В итоге кнопка вверх/вниз начинает не вверх и к текущему положению поднимать, а между текущим и предыдущем перемещать. а это неправильно

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, а если так? Обновил код.

Answer (score 2):

1. Добавьте переменную, хранящую последнее положение пользователя на странице (смещение).
2. Добавьте флаг "перемещаюсь".
3. Поставьте слушатель события скроллинга на документ. Пока флаг "перемещаюсь" активен - игнорировать скролл. Можно вместо игнора скролла сделать упорное следование до точки назначения или прерывание движения - как удобнее и как больше нравится.
4. При клике на кнопку - сохраняете смещение в переменную (можно добавить условие "смещение не равно 0" - я думаю, не стоит хранить нулевое смещение, а вот позиция на странице может пригодиться, при условии, что у нас только два варианта перемещения - в начало и в последнюю точку пребывания), выставляете флаг "перемещаюсь".
5. Перемещаетесь в топ или на целевую позицию по смещению.
6. После перемещения - снимаем флаг "перемещаюсь".

Comment: JS ведь объектно ориентированный язык, тогда что такое слушатель? и как его реализовать, есть статья которая поможет хотя бы в этом пункте разобраться?

Comment: Я имею в виду http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ или `.on( "scroll", handler )`.

Comment: Можете посмотреть ещё здесь про scroll: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283205/jquery-window-scrolling-event

Comment: А вот как остановить событие: http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp (`event.stopPropagation();`)